# how to add fontColor in ckeditor using vue-ckeditor?

Tags: vue.js, fonts, ckeditor

[ckeditor code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wVja.png)

I have installed the package using yarn add @ckeditor/ckeditor5-font. The path @ckeditor/ckeditor5-font/src/fontcolor exists in the data, but I don't know how to add it to my editor

I hope to add the functionality to change text color to my editor.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBrKX.png)